# Why routing does not accept normal conditional checking code in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I wanted to check some conditioning before the page loads, So I used resolve property 
as

```
 when('/home', { templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'homeController',resolve: {
            user: function () {
                if (localStorage.getItem('FBUserData') === null) {

                    $location.url('/login');
                }
            }()
        }}).
```

But this did not work, as it was showing the error like:

**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined** 
'
So I moved the function to controller and tried calling from there, but this gave different error:

Modified code

```
 var angAuth = angular.module('angularAuthApp'[...]);
    angAuth.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/home', { templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'homeController',resolve:homeController.checkUserFBSession})
    ....
    ....
    });
```

**And in homeController:**

```
angAuth.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $location) {    
    $scope.checkUserFBSession = function(){
      if(localStorage.getItem('FBUserData') === null){
          $location.url('/login');
      }
    };

...
});
```

Here after adding **resolve:homeController.checkUserFBSession**, I am getting the error like

**Failed to instantiate module angularAuthApp due to: homeController is not defined**

Comment: Feel free to also upvote the answer f you really liked it :)

Comment: Obviously you didn't like it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `resolve`'s value is *"an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated."*

This means that `user` needs to be evaluated **before** the controller is instantiated. Therefore you can't use a function defined in the controller to evaluate `user`.

---

You first approach should work thought (if properly implemented).

`resolve` is a **key-value** map, where `key` is the name of the dependency injected into the controller and `value` is either a string (denoting the name of a service) or a function. The function is called by Angular, but in your case you are calling it yourself and return undefined, so Angular sees undefined where it expects a function or a string.

You should change this:

```
user: function () {...}()
```

to that:

```
user: function ($location) {...}
```

Note: In order to use `$location` you also need to inject it into the function.

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6JUm4/)**.